# Best indexes for GROUP BY & equality query on joined tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, group-by

I have this recurrent SQL query in postgres:

```
SELECT b.name, COUNT(*)
FROM a JOIN b ON a.x = b.x
WHERE a.value = some_value
GROUP BY b.name;
```

(Count occurences of a.value for each b.name)

What are the best indexes to aid this query's efficiency? I'm assuming that for a.value a hash index on it helps. But what about the group by? Is there some composite index solution? Or another kind of solution?

Comment: Do you really want a JOIN here? If there a multiple rows in A that match the (hidden) join condition, the rows in B would be counted multiple times.

Comment: It's postgres, thanks I edited the post. Regarding the join, yes the point is to count the multiple occurences of the match. The natural join is just standing in for a primary key - foreign key relationship.

Comment: "*The natural join is just standing in for a primary key - foreign key relationship*" - no it doesn't. It joins on **all** columns that have the same _name_, not based on declared foreign keys.

Comment: Right, I do not have it as a natural join I just put it as such in this post to simplify the query but I now understand it is also relevant towards the question so I will edit it.

Comment: How selective is `a.value = some_value`?  Please show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` plan for the query as it currently runs.

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use `NATURAL JOIN`.  It is not clear what your query is actually doing.  It is easy to make mistakes.  And most importantly, the so-called "natural" join does not use the *natural* relationships explicitly declared using foreign key relationships.

Let me assume your query looks like this:

```
SELECT b.name, COUNT(*)
FROM a JOIN
     b 
     ON b.x = a.x
WHERE a.value = some_value
GROUP BY b.name;
```

In most databases, you would want the following indexes:

- `a(value, x)`
- `b(x, name)`

Comment: Right, I'm not using natural join, I'm actually using a JOIN like you mentioned with a.x=b.x. I wrote it like that because I believed it would not be relevant to the question - my bad. Knowing that x is a primary key on both tables, is your answer still the same? Also, are those indexes b-tree or hash? How would you implement them in SQL? (sorry, you might have been clear but I'm not aware of the index notation)

Comment: @DaltonicD . . . An index to satisfy the `where` conditions will help, even if both are primary keys.  You don't need the second index if `x` is already a primary key.  The type of index makes little difference; the default works quite fine.  Your question would need a lot more information to make a distinction among index types (some questions that come to mind are what are the where conditions?  how big is the table?  how much filtering?  is `name` unique)